# How to test a ternary operator with Jest and Testing Library in React

Tags: typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm having trouble performing a test on a ternary operator. The component is an EditBox, and inside it there is a ternary that checks the save permissions. I know I have to test both conditions but I don't know how to do it.

The ternary constant:

```
    const checkPermissionComment = decodedToken.authorities?.find((i: any) => permissionComment.includes(i));
```

My code:

```
                   <Footer>
                        <ActionContainer style={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}>
                            <ButtonCancel
                                data-testid="handleClose"
                                variant="outline"
                                onClick={() => handleClose()}>
                                {translate("label.cancel")?.toUpperCase()}
                            </ButtonCancel>
                            


                               {
                                checkPermissionComment ?
                                <ButtonSave
                                    data-testid="handleCloseBtn"
                                    variant="contained"
                                    color="secondary"
                                    onClick={() => onSubmit()}
                                    disabled={!(enable && checkPermissionComment)}
                                    >
                                        {translate('editStatus.saveButton')}
                                    </ButtonSave>
                                    :
                                    null
                            }
                        </ActionContainer>
                    </Footer>
```

I need to test the "checkPermissionComment", where it returns a "ButtonSave" or "null".

My test:

```
   test('ButtonSave -> onSubmit', async () => {
    const handleClose = jest.fn()
    render(
              <EditBox
                row={{}}
                open={true}
                handleClose={handleClose}
                refresh={() => (false)}
            />
    )
    
const button = screen.getByTestId('handleCloseBtn')
fireEvent.click(button);
console.log(button);

expect(screen.queryByTestId("handleCloseBtn")).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

But it's wrong, I've tried a few things and it doesn't work. At the moment, it is returning an error on the button:

```
const button: HTMLElement | null
Argument of type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element | Node | Document | Window'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element | Node | Document | Window'
```

Comment: What tests? Where do all of those variables come from and are they _all_ relevant to what you're asking? Give a [mre].

Comment: The long and the short of it is: there's two possible outcomes, so write one case for each of them.

Comment: sorry, I just edited with the test

Comment: That's still not something we can run, and includes no output. Re-read the guidance and give a **proper MRE**.

Comment: let me try again. I will edit the question

Comment: A was mentioned, you write 1 case where checkPermissionComment finds a permission, and one where it does not. You then, respectively `expect(screen.queryByTestId("handleCloseBtn").toBeInTheDocument();` and `expect(screen.queryByTestId("handleCloseBtn").not.toBeInTheDocument();`

Comment: Hello @Bastiat, its work, but I have a error: 

    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="handleCloseBtn"]

Comment: @barbaradsc Are you using queryBy or getBy. they are different. getBy assumes the element is there and will error out if it doesnt find  what it's looking for. queryBy permits a null return which is what you need to test a `.not.toBeInTheDocument();`

Comment: @Bastiat I tried this but it returned error on the button:
const button: HTMLElement | null Argument of type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element | Node | Document | Window'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element | Node | Document | Window'

Comment: @Bastiat was it supposed to be like this?

   const button = screen.queryByTestId('handleCloseBtn')
        fireEvent.click(button);
        console.log(button);

        expect(screen.getByTestId("handleCloseBtn")).toBeInTheDocument()
        expect(screen.queryByTestId("handleCloseBtn")).not.toBeInTheDocument()

Comment: @barbaradsc As  was mentioned earlier, go ahead and use codesandbox to create an example we can run and link that in your original post. Theres a few places where you issue might be but I cant tell which is likely the problem. You may just not be passing the testid down to the base html button component within <ButtonSave /> for instance.

Comment: The fact that this _still_ is not a MRE notwithstanding, that test is unlikely to pass given that you expect the same thing (`[data-testid="handleCloseBtn"]`) to both be in and not in the document. The specific error is because `queryBy` could return `null`, in which case what's `fireEvent.click` going to do?

Comment: hey guys, my problem is more complicated than expected, but i found someone to help me here in the company. Thank you so much to everyone who helped me